# Xtify push messages are not received on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, push, message, xtify

I have created an account on Xtify for receiving push messages via BIS on Blackberry. Sample application that ships with Xtify SDK works fine and registration requests' responses are successful(As shown on the sample app screen). Finally it prints to the screen that it is listening for incoming messages. When I send a notification from web console it says "Notifications were sent to blackberry users:". but no push message is received. Also note that I have used BlackBerry server SDK to receive push messages which I was writing for another application and it worked really well.

Since I am sure that the client application works, I tried with this service "http://notify.xtify.com/api/1.2/pn/push" to send push messages programmatically. Still it keeps giving this error whatever the value I put in there. I tried device pin, and other keys too. But still the same error.

Any help?

Comment: Does your device have an active data plan?

Comment: Of course I have an active BIS data plan. I also have used the same device to deliver push messages with the sample server that comes with BlackBerry push SDK. (In order to simplify the task I have turned to Xtify). Further debugging with the URL for submitting push messages I found that the service always returns "Invalid device tokens"(with both versions that accept xml and Json services), but the client application shows successful registration with BlackBerry server and Xtify servers.

Comment: In addition to above details, sample application that is downloaded with Xtify SDK works well because it can access push messages delivered from push initiator that is installed with BlackBerry push SDK.

Comment: After few attempts I managed to get a response like this by calling xtify push API                                                 <push-notification-response><blackberry><invalidDeviceIds/><invalidDeviceTokens/><message></message><notificationIds/><response>SUCCESS</response></blackberry></push-notification-response> but still push message is not delivered to device

Comment: Sorry, we couldn't replicate your experience using our sample implementation.